# ORM for MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, orm, morphia

I am quite keen to learn an ORM Framework for MongoDB.

I have come across Morphia but was unable to find any good tutorials or books on the same.

Can anybody suggest any better ORM Framework for MongoDB along with good tutorials/books?

Comment: FYI there is documentation, sample code, and FAQs on the [Morphia wiki](https://github.com/mongodb/morphia/wiki).

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you'll find a book in this special area, since it's a bit narrow. Writing a book is a lot of work and if there are only few potential customers, it won't pay off.

But you might want to get started by my presentation https://speakerdeck.com/xeraa/morphia-painfree-jpa-for-mongodb and the sample code https://github.com/xeraa/morphia-demo. That should get you started. And if you have any questions, there are already quite a lot of answers on StackOverflow or you can ask a new one.